# i want to use the turtle function to write out what i input

Tags: python, turtle-graphics, python-turtle

i have already made a turtle string to make every letter in the aphabet, and assigned them to functions, so i only have to print a() for it to write out an A for example. but what im wondering is if it is possible to have the user input a sentence or word, and then search through the input and find all letters used, then print those corresponding functions, to print out what is said in the input. i have no idea if this is even possible, but if it is i would like to know how.
thank you in advance.

Comment: Wouldn't simply looping through the character in the string and then call the individual functions to print out the characters suffice?

Comment: Yes you just make a map dictionary - `{'a': print_a, 'b':print_b}` and call it `my_dict['a']()`

Comment: @Sayse sorry, im very new to coding, but how would that look like completely?

Answer (score -1):

An easier way to do this is to use the turtle write function.

```
import turtle
my_text = input("type something: ")
turtle.write(my_text)
turtle.done()
```

turtle.done() is there to keep the turtle screen visible after it runs.

If you want to use a separate function for each letter you will need to split your input into letters and call the functions like was mentioned in the comments. This approach is called a dispatch table. Please edit your question to show what you have attempted so far.